# Template path from plugin not working from CP

Tags: plugin-development, emails

I've written a plugin that sends and email to a user group on new entry save in a particular section. Most entries will be made from the front end, and the plugin is working great in that regard. However, if a user attempts to create a new entry from the CP, the plugin cannot find my designated template path and throws an error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
if ($isNewEntry and $entrySection == 'Questions')
{
    //Get all users from UserGroup
    $user_criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
    $user_criteria->groupId = '9';
    $users = $user_criteria->find();
    $template = '/email/question-email.html';

    //Send to each User
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        //Send Mail
        $email = new EmailModel();
        $email->toEmail = $user->email;
        $email->subject = 'New Question';
        $email->htmlBody = "{% extends '{$template}' %}".
            "{% set body %}".
            '
            <p>A new question has been posted by '.$entry->author->name.':</p>

            <h2>Question: '.$entry->title.'</h2>

            <p>Description: '.$entry->questionDetails.'</p>

            <p>Attachments: '.$entry->questionAttachments->total().'</p>

            <p><a style="color: #09c;" href="'.$entry->url.'" title="'.$entry->title.'"><b>Answer Question</b></a></p>
                        '
            ."{% endset %}";

        craft()->email->sendEmail($email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to call [PathService::setTemplatesPath()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/PathService#setTemplatesPath-detail) and pass in the path to your plugin's template folder.

It would look something like:

```
// Save the current template path.
$originalPath = craft()->path->getTemplatesPath();

// Set your plugin's template path.
$path = craft()->path->getPluginsPath().'/mypluginfolder/templates/';
craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($path);

//Send to each User
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    //Send Mail
    $email = new EmailModel();
    $email->toEmail = $user->email;
    $email->subject = 'New Question';
    $email->htmlBody = "{% extends '{$template}' %}".
        "{% set body %}".
        '
        <p>A new question has been posted by '.$entry->author->name.':</p>

        <h2>Question: '.$entry->title.'</h2>

        <p>Description: '.$entry->questionDetails.'</p>

        <p>Attachments: '.$entry->questionAttachments->total().'</p>

        <p><a style="color: #09c;" href="'.$entry->url.'" title="'.$entry->title.'"><b>Answer Question</b></a></p>
                    '
        ."{% endset %}";

    craft()->email->sendEmail($email);
}

// Reset the original path.
craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($originalPath);
```